# Gulp - Инъекция содержания CSS,JS файлов в html страницу

Tags: node.js, gulp

Стоит задача с помощью Gulp задачи минифицировать CSS, JS фалы и вставить их содержание прямо в HTML страницу что бы уменьшить количество запросов на сервер. Вопрос: Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [gulp-include](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-include) для объединения файлов.

Структура файлов:

```
+-- dist
+-- src
|   +-- index.html
|   +-- main.css
|   +-- main.js
+-- node_modules
+-- gulpfile.js
+-- package.json
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    <!--=include main.min.css -->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    <!--=include main.min.js -->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    include = require("gulp-include"),
    cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css'),
    minify = require('gulp-minify');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    gulp.src('src/main.css')
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(rename('main.min.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));

    gulp.src('src/main.js')
        .pipe(minify({noSource: true}))
        .pipe(rename('main.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));

    gulp.src('src/index.html')
        .pipe(include({
            includePaths: [
                "dist"
            ]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```